# How to read values from the querystring with ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, query-string, .net-core

I'm building one RESTful API using ASP.NET Core MVC and I want to use querystring parameters to specify filtering and paging on a resource that returns a collection.

In that case, I need to read the values passed in the querystring to filter and select the results to return.

I've already found out that inside the controller `Get` action accessing `HttpContext.Request.Query` returns one `IQueryCollection`.

The problem is that I don't know how it is used to retrieve the values. In truth, I thought the way to do was by using, for example

```
string page = HttpContext.Request.Query["page"]
```

The problem is that `HttpContext.Request.Query["page"]` doesn't return a string, but a `StringValues`.

Anyway, how does one use the `IQueryCollection` to actually read the querystring values?

Answer (score 252):

You can use `[FromQuery]` to bind a particular model to the querystring:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding

e.g.

```
[HttpGet()]
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery(Name = "page")] string page)
{...}
```

Comment: I think the `[FromQuery]` attrib can also be ommited as the .net binding will check all the form inputs and url querystring params by default, except that you have some reason to limit its source.

Comment: (Name = "page") is unnecessary - it will bind to the variable if named the same

Comment: This is important if the querystring parameter name is structured. For example 'object.propname'

Answer (score 170):

You could use the ToString method on `IQueryCollection` which will return the desired value if a single `page` parameter is specified:

```
string page = HttpContext.Request.Query["page"].ToString();
```

if there are multiple values like `?page=1&page=2` then the result of the ToString call will be `1,2`

But as @mike-g suggested in his answer you would better use model binding and not directly accessing the `HttpContext.Request.Query` object.

Comment: The ToString is not necessary. The compiler will cast it implicitly, if you assign the query-value to a string..

Comment: Adding ToString() even dangerous. If the URL doesn't have a query string ID, the returned value would be null(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.querystring?view=netframework-4.8#examples ) and cause NullReference exception.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim no it's not, and no it won't, `StringValues` is a struct, it can't be null, in addition your link points to NET Framework article.

Comment: @AlexfromJitbit, you are right, in Asp.Net Core it returns StringValues.Empty if the key is not present. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iquerycollection.item?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-iquerycollection-item(system-string)

Comment: @Darin can you kindly check this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75846918/how-to-read-the-querystring-value-not-working

Answer (score 75):

ASP.NET Core will automatically bind `form values`, `route values` and `query strings` by name.  This means you can simply do this:

```cs
[HttpGet()]
public IActionResult Get(int page)
{ ... }
```

---

> MVC will try to bind request data to the action parameters by name ... below is a list of the data sources in the order that model binding looks through them
>
> 1. `Form values`: These are form values that go in the HTTP request using the POST method. (including jQuery POST requests).
> 2. `Route values`: The set of route values provided by Routing
> 3. `Query strings`: The query string part of the URI.

Source: [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?#sources)

---

FYI, you can also combine the automatic and explicit approaches:

```cs
[HttpGet()]
public IActionResult Get(int page
     , [FromQuery(Name = "page-size")] int pageSize)
{ ... }
```

Comment: While not the answer to the op's question, this is a very useful answer to those who came here for a similar reason.

Answer (score 48):

Here is a code sample I've used (with a .NET Core view):

```
@{
    Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues queryVal;

    if (Context.Request.Query.TryGetValue("yourKey", out queryVal) &&
        queryVal.FirstOrDefault() == "yourValue")
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvote for including the FULL object name (or the correct using statement).  Drives me nuts when people put just the objectname with no fully qualfied or at least a using statement.  Thanks.

Answer (score 37):

You can just create an object like this:

```
public class SomeQuery
{
    public string SomeParameter { get; set; }
    public int? SomeParameter2 { get; set; }
}
```

And then in controller just make something like that:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult FindSomething([FromQuery] SomeQuery query)
{
    // Your implementation goes here..
}
```

Even better, you can create API model from:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetSomething([FromRoute] int someId, [FromQuery] SomeQuery query)
```

to:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetSomething(ApiModel model)

public class ApiModel
{
    [FromRoute]
    public int SomeId { get; set; }
    [FromQuery]
    public string SomeParameter { get; set; }
    [FromQuery]
    public int? SomeParameter2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What’s a URL that this would apply to? I’m new to this so I can’t “backwards engineer” to the URL. Would it be something like http://example.com/somequery/findquery?someparameter1=1&someparameter2=2 ?

Comment: @Christian if you don't change any convention, it would be example.com/[controller]/[action]/{someid:int}?someparameter=1&someparameter2=2

Answer (score 25):

`StringValues` is an [array of strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.primitives.stringvalues?view=aspnetcore-2.1). You can get your string value by providing an index, e.g. `HttpContext.Request.Query["page"][0]`.

Comment: Thank you; this was the only response that actually answered the question. (In my case, I can't use binding because I have a more complex logic like "first try the query string, if that's missing try the session and so on".)

Comment: Perfect answer after searching evenrywhere

Answer (score 12):

`IQueryCollection` has a `TryGetValue()` on it that returns a value with the given key. So, if you had a query parameter called `someInt`, you could use it like so:

```
var queryString = httpContext.Request.Query;
StringValues someInt;
queryString.TryGetValue("someInt", out someInt);
var daRealInt = int.Parse(someInt);
```

Notice that unless you have multiple parameters of the same name, the `StringValues` type is not an issue.

Comment: To add to this answer, if you call StringValues.ToString() you can cast it directly to a string if that's what you need.

Comment: Future readers: fully qualified name "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IQueryCollection queryString = this.Request.Query;"  Mine was in "Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features, Version=3.1.0.0,"  and "Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues" (mine was in "Assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=3.1.2.0,")

Answer (score 11):

in .net core if you want to access querystring in our view use it like

```
@Context.Request.Query["yourKey"]
```

if we are in location where @Context is not avilable we can inject it like

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
@if (HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query.Keys.Contains("yourKey"))
{
      <text>do something </text>
}
```

also for cookies

```
HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["DeniedActions"]
```

Comment: No need for all that code. Just use @Context.Request.Query["yourKey"]

Comment: Yes @ShadiNamrouti you are right in view where \@Context is avilable we can use it like \@Context.Request.Query["yourKey"] 
but if we are in controller we need to inject the HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe it helps.
For get query string parameter in view

View:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
@{ Context.Request.Query["uid"]}
```

Startup.cs ConfigureServices :

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a better solution for this problem,

- request is a member of abstract class ControllerBase
- GetSearchParams() is an extension method created in bellow helper
  class.

`var searchparams = await Request.GetSearchParams();`

I have created a static class with few extension methods

```
public static class HttpRequestExtension
{
  public static async Task<SearchParams> GetSearchParams(this HttpRequest request)
        {
            var parameters = await request.TupledParameters();

            try
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < parameters.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (parameters[i].Item1 == "_count" && parameters[i].Item2 == "0")
                    {
                        parameters[i] = new Tuple<string, string>("_summary", "count");
                    }
                }
                var searchCommand = SearchParams.FromUriParamList(parameters);
                return searchCommand;
            }
            catch (FormatException formatException)
            {
                throw new FhirException(formatException.Message, OperationOutcome.IssueType.Invalid, OperationOutcome.IssueSeverity.Fatal, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }



public static async Task<List<Tuple<string, string>>> TupledParameters(this HttpRequest request)
{
        var list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();


        var query = request.Query;
        foreach (var pair in query)
        {
            list.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(pair.Key, pair.Value));
        }

        if (!request.HasFormContentType)
        {
            return list;
        }
        var getContent = await request.ReadFormAsync();

        if (getContent == null)
        {
            return list;
        }
        foreach (var key in getContent.Keys)
        {
            if (!getContent.TryGetValue(key, out StringValues values))
            {
                continue;
            }
            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                list.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(key, value));
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

in this way you can easily access all your search parameters. I hope this will help many developers :)

Comment: Am I missing something - where is FhirException defined, what name space is Task<SearchParams>  found in?

Answer (score 2):

Some of the comments mention this as well, but asp net core does all this work for you.

If you have a query string that matches the name it will be available in the controller.

https://myapi/some-endpoint/123?someQueryString=YayThisWorks

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("some-endpoint/{someValue}")]
public IActionResult SomeEndpointMethod(int someValue, string someQueryString)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(someValue);
        Debug.WriteLine(someQueryString);
        return Ok();
    }
```

Ouputs:

123

YayThisWorks

Answer (score 2):

1. `Startup.cs` add this service
   `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`
2. Your view add **inject** `@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor`
3. get your value

**Code**

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
@{
    var id = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["id"];

    if (id != null)
    {
        // parameter exist in your URL 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to access QueryString inside of an asp.net core view you can do it like this:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

@if (Context.Request.Query.Keys.Any())
{
    <button>--ClearFilters--</button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we usually can fetch data from routing in 3 way:
1.query string
2.query params
3.hybrid

I describe query string:

exp:

```
[HttpGet("Home/routing")]
public IActionResult privacy(String name)
{
return ViewModel:name
}
```

to pass name as querystring:

**url:port/Home/routing?name=Alex**

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the values from the `IQueryCollection`, you can use the indexer with the parameter name.

```
string page = HttpContext.Request.Query["page"].ToString(); // Convert to string if necessary
```

You can access individual querystring parameters by their names, and then use `.ToString()` to convert the `StringValues` to a string if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?