# How to make route attribute to pass parameters like api/test?n=23

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am able to get the route using this attribute -

```
[Route("api/[controller]?{n}")]
        [HttpGet("{n}")]
```

I have tried this but I had no luck.

```
  [HttpGet]
        public string Get([FromQuery(Name = "n")] long n)
```

However, my REST request is like -

```
http://<>/api/test?n=23
```

My API works with the REST API -

```
http://<>/api/test/23
```

I have tried changing the / with ? but no luck.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50468541/2309376)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read values from the querystring with ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577376/how-to-read-values-from-the-querystring-with-asp-net-core)

Comment: With `[Route("api/[controller]")]` on controller level, it should work with `[HttpGet]` 
 and `public string Get([FromQuery] long n)` on action.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found the solution yet please see below.

On your controller `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]`

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class TestController: Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetSomething([FromQuery]int id)
    {
      return Ok(id);
    }
}
```

This will yield the following route - http://localhost:5200/api/test/GetSomething?id=25