# How to handle unknown parameters in ASP.NET Core Actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, parameters, controller

How to handle unknown parameters in ASP.NET Core? When I use `[FromQuery]` it just ignores the unknown parameters, but ideally it should return 400 if the parameter is unknown so the caller knows it needs to fix the parameters?

Example: `GetRecords` tries to use any `StartDate` or `EndDate` from query string, use default value if they are not specified.

But if a query like `?StartTime=2021/2/15&EndTime=2021/2/16`, the code actually will return all records from DB as it treats like no parameters passed. Ideally it should throw an error to let caller know the parameter names are invalid.

```
class RecordQuery 
{
    public RecordQuery()
    {
       StartDate = DateTime.MinValue;
       EndDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    //...
}

class Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult<RecordsResult>> GetRecords([FromQuery] RecordQuery query)
    {
        // query db where date < query.EndDateTime && date > query.StartDateTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reject requests containing unknown query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55451408/reject-requests-containing-unknown-query-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You can see example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#the-puttodoitem-method

```
if(StartDate == null){
    return BadRequest();
}
```

Let's do the same thing with another input parameter(s) (query conditions)

If you want validate input parameter(s), use `[Required]` for model of `[FromQuery]`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19279419/3728901 . In your case, it is model `RecordQuery` .