# API Action - The value '1,2' is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

Using Asp.Net Core 2.2 I am calling an API using:

```
products?productsIds=1,2&offset=10&limit=4
```

But I get the error on model binding for productsIds:

```
The value '1,2' is not valid.
```

I tried with `productsIds=1` and in that case it works.

And `Offset` and `Limit` also get the correct values ...

The API model and action are:

```cs
public class Request {
  public IList<Int32> ProductsIds { get; set; }
  public Int32 Limit { get; set; }
  public Int32 Offset { get; set; }
}

[ApiController]
public class ProductController : ControllerBase {

  [HttpGet("products")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery]Request request) {
    // Action code
  }

}
```

What am I missing?

**Update**

This is not similar to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api) as the solution proposed in that question uses `[FromUri]`.

The attribute `[FromUri]` is not available in ASP.NET Core 2.2 `ApiController` ([Microsoft Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api)).

Comment: is there any data in the [FromQuery]Request request ?

Comment: You mean other parameters? Yes there is and they assume the correct values. I added some more information to may question. In fact if I use `productsIds=1` then it works.

Comment: Can you try HttpContext.Request.Query["ProductsIds"] to see if work ?

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577376/how-to-read-values-from-the-querystring-with-asp-net-core

Comment: Update: yes it works ... I get a string "1,2"

Answer (score 1):

Try this you can use HttpContext.Request.Query to get a params

like this

```cs
HttpContext.Request.Query["ProductsIds"]
```

Comment: But I do not wan to use HttpContext.Request.Query["ProductsIds"] ... I want the binding to be done automatically and I don't understand why ASP.NET core don't bind a simple List of Ints.

Comment: I understand but as I know the FromQuery can't get the array so you have to use this way

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass `List` as GET param use the following query

```
products?productsIds=1&productsIds=2
```