# I m looking for a REGEX to split a response with & as part of the value

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-core

So I get a response as pairs of keys and values
sum=199&name=arik&business=**arik & sons**&address=xyz

I m looking for a REGEX that will be able to split the keys and values

giving the following guidelines
1. first pair doesn't have the &
2. it could have & inside some of the values

Thank you

Comment: You don't need regex. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577376/how-to-read-values-from-the-querystring-with-asp-net-core)

Comment: @Eldar I need a regex cause it's a general method which gets all the responses and I cannot parse a specific key

Answer (score 0):

The most practical thing to do is use the uri class (even if it's a fake url) and then use HttpUtility.ParseQueryString