# Routing a redirect URL in Web Api .Net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am working on Github api Oauth.
The main problem is to match callback URl with method in Web Api

```
     [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/values/callback/{code}&{state}")]
    public JsonResult Get (string code, string state)
    {
        var s = User.Claims;
        return new JsonResult(s);
    }
```

In StartUp file:
`options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/api/values/callback/");`
Redirect in URL that should match an action in service
http://localhost:5000/api/values/callback/?code=b1b0659f6e0&state=CfDJ8Ir-xT
So, I can not build rout which has pattern /?param1&param2
Here is redirect URL  that should match :

Would be glad for help :)

Comment: I suspect `{code}&{state}` should be removed. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/a/41577446/34092 .

Comment: Hi, @Marrie, I already posted the code to solve your question. It works on me. If the answer solved your question, please mark it for helping more people. If not, we may be able to continue to explore solutions. Thank you for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[FromQuery]` to get values from the query string.

```
    [HttpGet] 
    [Route("api/values/callback")]
    public JsonResult Get([FromQuery]string code, string state)
    {
        string s = "code:" + code + "         state:" + state;
        return new JsonResult(s);
    }
```

> Test

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using OidClient you can use the following to inject the service to the method and get the querystring to process.

```cs
// route method here
public async Task<ActionResult> ProcessCallback([FromServices] HttpListenerRequest request){
...

// generate the options using `OidcClientOptions`
 var client = new OidcClient(options);
        var result = await client.ProcessResponseAsync(request.QueryString.ToString(), null);
...

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to edit the route to api/values/callback/code={code}&state={state} .